# ROS time across machines

Tags: ros, multiplemachines, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When there are several machines involved, how are timestamps created? It looks like to me that they're being generated by each machine's individual time, so if one machine is out of sync with another than all the messages will be in the past or the future. Is this actually the case or am I missing something, and how do people deal with this limitation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11570/ros-time-across-machines/) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2011-10-17

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're correct, they just use the system's current time.  The typical way I've seen to synchronize time across computers is to use [Chrony](http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/).  With Ubuntu, you should be able to just run `apt-get install chrony`.

Here are some resources I've found on a quick search:

http://answers.ros.org/question/2140/chrony-configuration-and-limitations

http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter13#Clock_Synchronization

The important information is that your ROS system computers are tightly coupled in time, but loosely tied to the outside world's time.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Den](https://answers.ros.org/users/82056/den/) on 2022-03-28**:
If anyone requires, the link for: http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter13#Clock_Synchronization has been changed to: https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/downloads/pr2/pr2_manual_r321.pdf since PR2 has changed hands from Willow Garage to Clear Path Robotics

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're exactly right, the timestamps are generated from each machine's individual clock. So it's very important to keep all clocks synchronized. On the PR2 robot (which contains two machines) we use [Chrony](http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/).

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-10-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4